# Python: pass an argument to be displayed in the input() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a way to pass an argument to the input function?  what I would like to do is have the console output look like this

```
Enter data for row 0:
Enter data for row 1:
Enter data for row 2:
```

However when I add `row` to the input I get the below error.  Is there a way to display the row count when accepting input from the user?

TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

```
def get_matrix():
    matrix = []
    for row in range(0, 3):
        value = input("Enter data for row : ", row).strip()
        <do stuff>
    return matrix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only accepts one argument (the prompt), but you may simply format the string:

```
input(f"Enter data for row {row}: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do as well:

```
def get_matrix():
    matrix = []
    for row in range(0, 3):
        value = input("Enter data for row %d: "%row).strip()
        <do stuff>
    return matrix
```